# REStApi connection to qliksense for neo4j

Tags: rest, neo4j, qliksense

I am trying to connect to neo4j database to qliksense using REST Api connection but though Iam getting connection as successful it is returning a web URL output as csv. could anybody please guild me?

below are the properties i have set

url: http://serveraddress:7474/browser/db/staging/tx/cypher

method:post

request body:

```
{  

"Statements":[

"statement":"match(n:Customer) return n limit 5"

]

}

 

content-type:application/json

X-Stream=true

Accept:application/json
```

Basic auth :using userid and passwor

I am getting as connection success but when i try to select the data and view it is showing as csv with no data

Comment: What does "match(n:Customer) return n limit 5" return in Neo4j Browser?

Comment: it returns customer node details